# libreoffice calc concatenation of strings, function name in different language

Tags: function, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

The function =CONCATENATE("troll1","troll2") can concatenate strings, but in translated version of application, function names are different, so how can I easily find equivalent of english function in trollish or any other language even if destination language is completely unknown for me? Google Translate can not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to translate the names manually. If the user has selected trollish as i18n language and if he has disabled using english function names in calc (Menu `Tools` -> `Options` -> `LibreOffice Calc` -> `Formula` -> `Formula options`), he will see the corresponding function name in trollish.

The user may prefer keeping the language setting to trollish and use english just for the function names - voila:

[image]

To see the names in different language versions, open the [**`LibreOffice Wiki page regarding Text Functions`**](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Text_Functions), and choose a different language from the header bar:

[image]

[image]